# Checking for equality if either input can be `str` or `bytes`

Tags: python, string, bytestream

I am trying to write a function that checks if two strings (with ASCII-only content) or bytes are equal.

Right now I have:

```py
import typing as typ


def is_equal_str_bytes(
    a: typ.Union[str, bytes],
    b: typ.Union[str, bytes],
) -> bool:
    if isinstance(a, str):
        a = a.encode()
    if isinstance(b, str):
        b = b.encode()
    return a == b
```

This works with the any combination of `str` or `bytes` types, while the `==` operator will return `False` (rightfully) if the two types differ.

```
import itertools


ss = "ciao", b"ciao"
for a, b in itertools.product(ss, repeat=2):
    print(f"{a!r:<8} {b!r:<8} {is_equal_str_bytes(a, b)} {a == b}")
# 'ciao'   'ciao'   True True
# 'ciao'   b'ciao'  True False
# b'ciao'  'ciao'   True False
# b'ciao'  b'ciao'  True True
```

Is there a simpler / faster way?

Comment: How long are your strings?

Comment: Anywhere between a few chars and a few million chars.

Comment: I am a bit doubtful about the underlying problem you are trying to deal with: where do these string come from? If it's stuff coming from random places (such that you don't know what their type is) how can you know that the encoding used by the default `encode()` (which is system/environment dependent) is sensible for your comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some benchmarks with random equal strings/bytes of a million characters ([on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVPRbtswDHzXVxwydLZSL0tcoAuK5WHfURSGVNOLgFgyRKVNvj6T7DRO3FUv1t2RJ9KiumPYOvuw7vzpZNrO@QDHovGuRTAtmYAz66kjFYSw2GC1nM8fhY47fQzE@QHfsSp/oXEeBxgbLRZ7r2zt2txKKThFLmp6dTXlUihmio5bxducJTabYaulEExh38XoLMuGIqqqVcZW1UcZXEALLm8MgW/4s3tXR0bjibdgh1h47Yhtls55I6j@DHBwnmqonSdVHyF0cuIF2dvS4gGGYV3cIbYBfcFapNIEHTqfunoWiCsbHbJiwsz2ofmxnv1HUPxqzCiM/Xxiph6jMPHg9DO5vMQlqMtRvcdMzUb1HvoK78jG67hGejR@flotl8uXT33qD2FafMz4OuWLnPNE3EA9UcuJPGIO/io5oTE3Tu@12MNefREiTW2VpjZO7F/KH@RTH5RoSnR/1wOXlt23mnz/CpYwzSAvjK3pkJPE7xvi0pIE7ZiwutiE6NAamw/vKqcC/ewXZ//N8JESP8/MJbPzxoY8u1svygZ7RoY75AFzrOhRFiApxih5Ov0D) with Python 3.8 pre-release, but I got similar times with 3.10.2):

```
  186.88 us  s.encode()
  187.39 us  s.encode("utf-8")
  183.85 us  s.encode("ascii")
   94.62 us  b.decode()
   94.27 us  b.decode("utf-8")
  137.91 us  b.decode("ascii")
   79.93 us  s == s2
   82.69 us  b == b2
  182.72 us  s + "a"
  177.06 us  b + b"a"
    0.08 us  len(s)
    0.07 us  len(b)
    1.14 us  s[:1000].encode()
    0.97 us  b[:1000].decode()
    2.06 us  s[::1000].encode()
    1.45 us  b[::1000].decode()
    1.91 us  hash(s)
    1.56 us  hash(b)
  508.62 us  hash(s2)
  546.00 us  hash(b2)
    2.85 us  str(s)
 9142.59 us  str(b)
13541.64 us  repr(s)
 9100.34 us  repr(b)
```

Thoughts based on that:

- I thought for simpler code, maybe we could apply `str` or `repr` to both of them and then somehow compare the resulting strings (like after removing `b` prefixes) but the benchmark shows that that would be very slow.
- Getting the lengths is very cheap, so I'd compare those first. Return `False` if different, otherwise continue.
- If you've hashed them already or are going to afterwards anyway, then you could compare the hashes (and return `False` if different, otherwise continue). See [ASCII str / bytes hash collision](https://peps.python.org/pep-0456/#ascii-str-bytes-hash-collision) for why equal ASCII string and ASCII bytes have the same hash. (But I'm not sure it's guaranteed by the language, so it might not be safe, I'm not sure). Note that hashing the first time is slow (see times for hashing `s2`/`b2`) but subsequent lookups of the stored hash is fast (see times for hashing `s`/`b`).
- Decoding seems faster than encoding, so do that instead.
- Only decode if the types differ (one is string and one is bytes), otherwise just use `==`.
- It's wasteful to decode a million bytes if already the first one is a mismatch. So might be worth it to decode/compare chunks of shorter length instead of the whole thing, or test some short prefix or cross section before testing the whole thing.

So here's some potentially faster one using the above optimizations (not tested/benchmarked, partly because it depends on your data):

```
import typing as typ

def is_equal_str_bytes(
    a: typ.Union[str, bytes],
    b: typ.Union[str, bytes],
) -> bool:
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    if hash(a) != hash(b):
        return False
    if type(a) is type(b):
        return a == b
    if isinstance(a, bytes):  # make a=str, b=bytes
        a, b = b, a
    if a[:1000] != b[:1000].decode():
        return False
    if a[::1000] != b[::1000].decode():
        return False
    return a == b.decode()
```

My benchmark code:

```
import os
from timeit import repeat

n = 10**6
b = bytes(x & 127 for x in os.urandom(n))
s = b.decode()
assert hash(s) == hash(b)

setup = '''
from __main__ import s, b
s2 = b.decode()  # Always fresh so it doesn't have a hash stored already 
b2 = s.encode()
assert s2 is not s and b2 is not b
'''

exprs = [
    's.encode()',
    's.encode("utf-8")',
    's.encode("ascii")',
    'b.decode()',
    'b.decode("utf-8")',
    'b.decode("ascii")',
    's == s2',
    'b == b2',
    's + "a"',
    'b + b"a"',
    'len(s)',
    'len(b)',
    's[:1000].encode()',
    'b[:1000].decode()',
    's[::1000].encode()',
    'b[::1000].decode()',
    'hash(s)',
    'hash(b)',
    'hash(s2)',
    'hash(b2)',
    'str(s)',
    'str(b)',
    'repr(s)',
    'repr(b)',
]

for _ in range(3):
    for e in exprs:
        number = 100 if exprs.index(e) < exprs.index('hash(s)') else 1
        t = min(repeat(e, setup, number=number)) / number
        print('%8.2f us ' % (t * 1e6), e)
    print()
```

Comment: Decoding vs encoding: at least in the UTF-8 case, encoding is always possible, decoding can fail

Comment: @MatteoItalia But surely not *"with ASCII-only content"*? (As stated by the question)

Comment: Right; in that case I'd force `.decode('ascii')`, which should error out if the precondition does not hold, and could possibly be faster.

Comment: @MatteoItalia See my benchmark again, it was *slower*.

Comment: Hmm it hurts that it's formally incorrect for a hypothetical encoding where the low 127 bytes don't match ASCII; also, it may be slower if the current codec is a "bad" one. If the `'utf-8'` case didn't match the "empty" one I would have guessed that there's some fast path for the "current encoding" case, and the codec lookup/instantiation time hurts for short strings. I'll do some tests as well.

Comment: BTW, running your code on my machine (Python 3.8.10, Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit with `it_IT.UTF-8` locale) has opposite results:   `38.95 us  s.encode()`, `38.79 us  s.encode("utf-8")` `38.64 us  s.encode("ascii")` `83.04 us  b.decode()` `83.09 us  b.decode("utf-8")` `85.06 us  b.decode("ascii")`. `encode` faster, `ascii` same as `utf-8`.

Comment: Looking at https://peps.python.org/pep-0393/, it seems like it's expected: after 3.3 if you have a `str` that is only ASCII-only it's probably going to be stored in memory directly as a ASCII bytes sequence, so conversion to `bytes` is going to be pretty much just a plain `memcpy`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Fascinating that we get opposite results. I'd *expect* encoding to be faster, as I also think it just needs to memcpy (after looking up its internal `is_ascii` flag, although I'm not sure that's always set and perhaps it's ignored for this for speed reasons, like I also think string equality comparisons ignore the hashes, which is btw why in my possible solution I checked hashes myself first). For `bytes` I'm not aware of an `is_ascii` flag, so it might have to check that in addition to the memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no simpler way to do it, if typing everything to str for processing purposes straight from the source is not an option.

If you want to make the function itself marginally faster, you can add another check for reducing unnecessary translations off the bat:

```
if type(a) == type(b):
    return a == b
```

Third option would be introducing a new subclass, derivative of str for example and adding a comparison function - or a dummy `decode()` function. Then use that instead of the builtin class with `__builtin__.str = my_str`.